# how to Stop/Kill Rengine thread

Tags: java, r, multithreading, rjava

i'm trying to kill/stop Rengine thread but i can't, even if call `end()` method also. see the bellow peace of code.

```
Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);
----
----
engine.end();
System.out.println("engine::: "+engine);
```

the result of sysout is

```
engine::: Thread[Thread-0,5,]
```

then how to kill my Rengine thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your engine is already closed. After I call .end() on the Rengine it quits, and after that if there is no code to run the java main() exits as well normally.
If I put `System.out.println("engine::: "+engine);` before the main() exit and after calling engine.end() I too get engine::: Thread[Thread-1,5,main].

The sysout is just printing the reference to the Rengine object that you created. E.g. if you did `Rengine engine = new Rengine (new String [] {"–vanilla"}, false, null);` then when you print engine after the end() call, it is just printing the reference of the engine object.

Hope this helps else read here: [What is Object Reference Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504084/what-is-object-reference-variable)