# Array assignment and reference in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reference

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] b = a;
        int[] c = {6, 7, 8};
        a = c;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i ++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i ++) 
            System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I have initialized array a and assigning reference of a to new array b. Now I initialized a new array c and passed its reference to array a. Since array b is reference to array a, b should have new values that are in c but b is having old values of a. What is the reason behind it? 
Output is given below -

Output -

```
6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thats fine this is how each programming language  works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Don't be irritated by the name 'list'. The images are taken from a python visualization, but the principle is the same in Java*

Array `a` is assigned with a new array:

[image: Assigning a]

Array `b` is assigned to the instance behind `a`:

[image: Assigning b]

Array `c` is assigned with a new array:

[image: Assigning c]

And finally `a` is assigned to the instance behind `c`, `b` was not re-assigned and still keeps a reference to the old `a`:

[image: Re-Assigning a]

*Images taken from a visualization on pythontutor.com*

Answer (score 1):

When you assigned value of a to b, it means b is referring to same space allocated to array a. This means b will pick up any changes made to the array a, but if any changes made to the variable a. If a is made to refer to new array, b will still refer the old a reference.

```
b = a;  // b basically referring to memory used by array a
a = c;  // reference pointed by a has changed, but b is still referring the old array a
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `b=a` b references to a. However when you to `a=c` a is referring to c, but still b refers to the old object (address of this object as value been assigned and it is constant) `a` that you assigned because that is what it contains when you assigned.

Unless you reassign it, it won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you think of an object as a house, and a *reference* as a piece of paper with the address of a house written on it.  `a`, `b`, and `c` are all references.  So when you say

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

you're building a house with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 in it; and `a` is a piece of paper with the address of that house.

```
    int[] b = a;
```

`b` is another reference, which means it's another piece of paper.  But it has the address of the same house on it.

```
    int[] c = {6, 7, 8};
    a = c;
```

Now we build a new house and put 6, 7, and 8 into it.  `c` will be a piece of paper with the address of the new house.  When we say `a = c`, then the slip of paper that used to be `a` is thrown out, and we make a new piece of paper with the address of the new house.  That's the new value of `a`.

But `b` was a separate piece of paper.  It hasn't changed.  Nothing we've done has changed it.

References are like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

[What is Object Reference Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504084/what-is-object-reference-variable)

You have 2 objects (the arrays) and 3 references (a, b, c) to the objects. You're just swapping around where things are pointed.